# TinyMCE MenuButton image not appearing

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to add a menubutton to my tinyMCE toolbar. It seems to be working but for some reason the image is not being set

```
editor.addButton(
    'sptemplate'
    , {
        title   : 'Add Caution / Warning'
        ,image  : '/images/tinymce/tinymce-ico-template.png'
        ,type   : 'menubutton'
        ,menu   : [{
                    text: 'Add Caution',
                    value: templates.Caution,
                    icon: true,
                    image: '/images/tinymce/tinymce-ico-caution.png',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.insertContent(this.value());
                    }}
                   ,{
                    text: 'Add Warning',
                    value: templates.Warning,
                    icon: true,
                    image: '/images/tinymce/tinymce-ico-warning.png',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.insertContent(this.value());
                    }}]
    }
);
```

This is adding the button with the 2 menu options. The icons are appearing for the two options but not for the `Add Caution / Warning` parent.

When I inspect the element I see this:

```
<button id="mceu_14-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="mce-ico mce-i-sptemplate"></i>
    <span></span> 
    <i class="mce-caret"></i>
</button>
```

[image]

Can someone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It seems to be something to do with the button `type`. In the screenshot in the OP, you can see the icon appearing for the last button in the toolbar. This is the same image url, the only difference is that I'm not specifying the `menubutton` type

Comment: If I comment out the `type:menuButton` then the icon appears, but I lose my dropdown options (`warning` and `caution`)

Answer (score 0):

Use "icon" and not "image".
For example:

```
title   : 'Add Caution / Warning',
icon   : 'caution-warning',
type   : 'menubutton'
```

and in your css file:

```
i.mce-i-caution-warning {
     background-image: url('../images/caution-warning.png'); /* write the correct path */
}
```